# Treat TO_NUMBER() invalid format errors as NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a string column which usually contains integers in two formats... zero-padded, and not:

- 5
- 05

I want to sort based on these values numerically.  To do that I do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM things ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(num, '0000');
```

This works fine, but sometimes there is invalid data, like `abc`, or `!@#` in this column.  Postgres becomes unhappy with me:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: " "

What I'd like to do is treat invalid values/failures of `TO_NUMBER()` as `NULL` so that they are sorted accordingly.  Is this possible?  Or, some other alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PostgreSQL, you can use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM things ORDER BY 
TO_NUMBER((case when num ~ '^[0-9\.]+$' THEN num else '0' end),'0000');
```

Comment: For anyone else looking at this answer, I modified MauroB's solution as follows:  `CASE WHEN num ~ '^[0-9]{1,4}$' THEN TO_NUMBER(num, '0000') ELSE NULL END`.  That way, I could also use `ASC NULLS LAST` in my sort if I wanted.  I'm also limiting to integers between 1-4 digits in my case.  Thanks again Mauro for the excellent suggestion!